# Create text data type in sequel migration

Tags: ruby, sequel, padrino

`alter_table(:pages) do
      add_column :about, Text
    end`

when running the migration `rake sq:migrate` I get

`rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Text`

How do i create a text data type. I did follow the docs but sequel doc has very less eg.

### Update 1

I can use Text :about when creating a table in migration but the issue persist in altering table

Comment: Are you using Rails?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, nope. Using padrino

Comment: Try to change ```Text``` as ```"Text"```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely figured this out already, but you can specify a `text` data type in Sequel like so:

```
alter_table(:pages) do
  add_column :about, String, text: true
end
```

See [documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html) for more details.

This works also and is more concise:

```
alter_table(:pages) do
  add_column :about, :text
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/schema_modification.rdoc